# How to access antd less variables when defining a css module for a component?

Tags: less, antd, react-css-modules

I'm using customize-cra as suggested by antd documentation to be able to customize the theme and it works fine.
I can access less variables from antd theme by importing the index in my less files and it works fine.
I can use the old fashioned css modules to style my components by defining files with `.module.css` and it works fine.
However, I would like to import and use the antd theme less variables in my css modules and I can't figure out how to make it work. Does anybody know how it can be achieved?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to use the variables if I import `antd.less` at the top of the `whatevercomponent.less` file:

```
@import 'antd/dist/antd.less';
```